# what brand of thermostat is this

Tags: thermostat

The cover is missing from this thermostat, so I don't what brand or model it is and I don't have the manual for it.  [image]

Answer (score 6):

Most residential thermostats are designed to be easily removed on one of two ways:

- The entire device slides up ~ 1/2" and then pulls off the mounting screws
- The front pulls forward, possibly with a plastic tab or two on top or bottom pried open with a flat screwdriver, revealing a back panel screwed into wall and containing the connections to the wires going to the furnace & air conditioning.

Either way, once you have it off the wall it is usually easy to find manufacturer/model information.

Answer (score 4):

That is a Noma thermostat. It's a pretty junky thermostat. I believe that one pulls straight of the mounting bracket. It may be branded differently than Noma but I recognized it immediately.

[image]
[Varage Sale](https://www.varagesale.com/i/jf6uae6r-noma-thermostat)

Answer (score 0):

Probably its a Noma THM302M or a 303M.